# Visual Basic 6 Regular Expression [Hexadecimal] failing to replace properly

Tags: regex, vb6, hex

I'm trying to replace  native x86 asm to C++ code so I can make a emulator.

I got this

```
If ereg(ASM, "PUSH ([A-F0-9\s]+)", False) Then
    ASM = ereg_replace(ASM, "PUSH ([A-F0-9\s]+)", _
    "regs.d.esp -= 4;" & vbNewLine & _
    "*(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = $1;", False)
End If
```

Functions I found on the internet.. should work.. as they are on google.

```
Function ereg(strOriginalString, strPattern, varIgnoreCase)
    ' Function matches pattern, returns true or false
    ' varIgnoreCase must be TRUE (match is case insensitive) or FALSE (match is case sensitive)
    Dim objRegExp: Set objRegExp = New RegExp
    With objRegExp
        .Pattern = strPattern
        .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase
        .Global = True
    End With
    ereg = objRegExp.test(strOriginalString)
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function

Function ereg_replace(strOriginalString, strPattern, strReplacement, varIgnoreCase)
    ' Function replaces pattern with replacement
    ' varIgnoreCase must be TRUE (match is case insensitive) or FALSE (match is case sensitive)
    Dim objRegExp: Set objRegExp = New RegExp
    With objRegExp
        .Pattern = strPattern
        .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase
        .Global = True
    End With
    ereg_replace = objRegExp.Replace(strOriginalString, strReplacement)
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

I start up with.

```
/* 401187 */
PUSH 466F20
```

and want to end up with..

```
/* 401187 */
regs.d.esp -= 4;
*(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = 466F20;
```

But function above, ran ends up with..

```
/* 401187 */
regs.d.esp -= 4;
*(unsigned int *)(regs.d.esp) = 466F20
;
```

..Err don't worry about it not being 0x466F20; (that I will do later with a second pass).

Comment: "...should work...as they are on google."  This is a poor assumption

Comment: ^ joke, but it looks like a trusted nice blog source http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/vbscript-regular-expressions/  I am obviously not using it properly. Probably the C++ syntax symbols conflicting with regular expression

Comment: Please don't (ab)use regular expressions like this. You need to write a parser.

Comment: i did write a parser for most of it.. as PUSH (EAX|EBX|ECX|ESI|EDI) etc... but with numbers.. I don't want to mess with my parser to make it more complicated then it already is. Btw ASM = 1 line of assembly code.. not a WHOLE block.

Comment: Almost fixed it myself.. updated post with newest code.. now problem is the semicolon always gets placed on a new line instead of after the hexadecimal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bad regular expression...

instead of

`"PUSH ([A-F0-9\s]+)"`

I had to use

`"PUSH ([A-F0-9]+)"`

`\s` was capturing new lines.